# Set column height equal to height of record in List

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, json, json-formatting, column-formatting

I have a SP list where one of the columns is multi-line I have therefore set the style of this specific column as `"height":"auto"` which works perfectly for this column.

I then have other formatted columns which change color based on their values however the div is a fixed height.  I want the height of the div to equal the height of the list item.  I have tried using `"height":"100%"` and `"auto"` and neither work.

Is there a way I can reference the height of the list item or even reference the height of another column withing the list?

I am using JSON column formatting for this task and I do not have access to SharePoint Designer.

[image: SP list with dynamic height]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is **Not Possible using column formatting**, you cannot access the CSS properties of other columns.

Using column formatting, You can only access the column values from the same list item/row like `[$AnotherColumnFromSameRow]`.

Where `AnotherColumnFromSameRow` is internal name of another column from same list item/row. You can get the internal name of your column by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

**Workaround**:

You need to use the **View Formatting** and define the look and feel for the complete row on your own (Note that you will loose some of the default functionalities given by SharePoint).

**References**:

1. [Use view formatting to customize SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-formatting).
2. [View formatting Samples](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-list-formatting/tree/master/view-samples).

Comment: Thanks, I don't think what I am trying to achieve is possible in this case because I already have an AdditionalRowClass which would be overwritten.  I can live without the boxes stretching down anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create Custom Column by IFieldEditor

check this 
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862248(v%3Doffice.14)

and

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/jj126861(v=office.14)?redirectedfrom=MSDN